# Meteor - Special characters in Blaze

Tags: meteor, special-characters

I am subscribed to something which returns a list of object from database. In the template, I want to access one of the properties of the object. I tried:

`{{property.en-GB}}`

but that generates an error server-side on the minus sign (`-`). And then I tried:

`{{property['en-GB']}}`

but that returns an error in the client console:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: Can't call non-function: [object Object]
```

So with the assumption that I cannot alter the database, how can I access this property containing a special character? (It might not be limited to only `-`)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the documentation [here](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spacebars), I guess the answer for your question is:

```
{{property.['en-GB']}}
```

So you were kind of close.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although what you proposed did get rid of the errors, the results still shows up empty. And I checked it on the Chrome console and there's definitely something there. I'm 99% it's something stupid on my end, but I can't think anymore, I guess I'll try again next week =_= Thanks again for your answer

Comment: If it shows empty then `property` is probably empty in the first place. Please start by verifying that.

Comment: I don't know why your suggestion didn't work for me, it just shows up empty. And I couldn't figure it out. As a subpar alternative, I used a helper to extract the text. `entext: function() {return this.text['en-GB'];}` Thank you for your help!

Comment: And it work? If so, then you should probably use `this` instead of `property`, so `{{this.['en-GB']}}`. I don't know your source code, just using the variables you suggested should work.